# Setting Key/Value Pairs

Tags: c#

I've created a List as a property of the class, and want to set the Key/Value pairs when defining the List. I was originally using a structure but realized it's probably not the ideal solution so I changed it to a List. The problem is I'm getting an error with the syntax.

Any ideas?

```
private List<KeyValuePair<String,String>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>[]
    {
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>("lsd",""),
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>("charset", "")
    };
```

Comment: At a guess, and without knowing the error, it's the `[]` pair at the end of the first line (it could also be the `;` char after the first KeyValuePair, it should be a `,`. Can you provide the error you're getting, save us copying and pasting your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably I'm missing something, but I would have used a Dictionary instead of
So simple....

```
Dictionary<string, string>formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"lsd", "first"},
    {"charset", "second"}
};
```

and then use it in these ways:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string>k in formData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(k.Value);
}
....
if(formData.ContainsKey("lsd"))
    Console.WriteLine("lsd is already in");
....    
string v = formData["lsd"];
Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Comment: I haven't used C# - or programmed - for over a year, so was going by what I remembered. But certainly is a better solution.

Comment: What I have to do in case where my data have same values?

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question. You will find more help than asking for a solution through a comment on a 5 year old question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<String,String>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("lsd",""),
    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("charset", "")
};
```

You had an extra `[]` in your definition. You are not creating an array, so you don't need it. Also when initializing list with some values, the values should be separated by a comma (`,`).

In my opinion, a better approach would be to use [`Tuple` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
pirvate List<Tuple<string, string>> formData = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
{
    new Tuple<string, string>("lsd",""),
    new Tuple<string, string>("charset", "")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the semi-colon to a comma on the third line and remove the square brackets from the first line.

```
private List<KeyValuePair<String,String>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>
{
        new KeyValuePair<String, String>("lsd",""),
        new KeyValuePair<String, String>("charset", "")
};
```

Incidentally, if you change it to a Dictionary you get the ability to look up the values by their key more easily.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `[]` from the declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<KeyValuePair<String,String>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>()
    {
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>("lsd",""),
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>("charset", "")
    };
```

1. Why `[]` after the constructor?
2. Items within collection initializer has to be separated using comma: `,`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
           private List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>
    {
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>("lsd",""),
            new KeyValuePair<String, String>("charset", "")
    };
```